# Republish Tomcat Server in Eclipse without complete Restart

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

In my Eclipse I have created a Dynamic Web Project, which runs on a Tomcat7. If I modify and save any file in the project, eclipse automatically republishes the project on the Tomcat (copies files in a temporary Tomcat directory) and restarts the Tomcat. This means I loose all sessions.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to automatically copy modified files in the Tomcat directory but only restart the Tomcat when manually restarting Tomcat?

Even better would be: Copy any modified files in Tomcat directoy but restart Tomcat only when I modified a file with extention *.java

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you set the development param to '1' in Tomcat web.xml config file?

Comment: You could try using Pivotal Tc Server. It handles hot swapping files very well, and even Java classes. It's just Tomcat with some extras.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Since I don't want to use extra software, I am very happy with Baldurian's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should start Tomcat in hot deploy mode (supported only in debug mode). There is a good guide for this [here](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/).

Comment: this solved my problem with uncheck one single option! thank you Baldurian

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deploy web applications to a running Tomcat server.

If the Host autoDeploy attribute is `"true"`, the Host will attempt to deploy and update web applications dynamically, as needed, for example if a new `.WAR` is dropped into the appBase. For this to work, the Host needs to have background processing enabled which is the default configuration.

autoDeploy set to "true" and a running Tomcat allows for:

- Deployment of `.WAR` files copied into the Host appBase.
- Deployment of exploded web applications which are copied into the Host appBase.
- `Re-deployment of a web application which has already been deployed from a .WAR when the new .WAR is provided.` In this case the exploded web application is removed, and the .WAR is expanded again. Note that the explosion will not occur if the Host is configured so that `.WARs are not exploded with a unpackWARs attribute set to "false"`, in which case the web application will be simply redeployed as a compressed archive.
- Re-deployment of a web application if the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file (or any other resource defined as a WatchedResource) is updated.
- Re-deployment of a web application if the Context Descriptor file from which the web application has been deployed is updated.
- Re-deployment of a web application if a Context Descriptor file (with a filename corresponding to the Context path of the previously deployed web application) is added to the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory.
- Undeployment of a web application if its document base (docBase) is deleted. Note that on Windows, this assumes that anti-locking features (see Context configuration) are enabled, otherwise it is not possible to delete the resources of a running web application.

> Note that web application reloading can also be configured in the
>   loader, in which case loaded classes will be tracked for changes.

For more details, you can follow this [tutorial](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server)

### Related Link:

- [Tomcat Deploy Procedures](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-deploy-procedures)
- [Hot Deployment](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/9780596101060/ch03s05.html)
- [How to configure hot deploy in Eclipse?](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/)

Comment: I think this doesn't work with eclipse servers plugin, but manually deploy your web project as a war. Since i don't deploy my project as a war file and Baldurian's solution already worked for my, I didn't test your solution. But i thank you for posting!